# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k (k+3)}$

Tags: limits

> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k (k+3)}
> $$

Calculate the limit as $n$ tends to infinity I've tried to evaluate using integrals but was unable to find the answer, the answer given is $(e-2)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to write

$$\frac{1}{k+3} = \int_0^1 x^{k+2}dx$$

so

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n^k} {n \choose k} \frac{1}{k+3} &= \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n^k} {n \choose k} \int_0^1 x^{k+2}dx \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n^k} {n \choose k} x^{k+2}dx \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 x^2 \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^ndx, \ \text{(integrand converges uniformly)} \\ 
&= \int_0^1 x^2 e^x dx\\
&= e^x(x^2-2x+2) \big{|}_0^1 \\
&= e-2\\\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: +1 Perhaps cite the limit theorem used when you move the limit inside the integral.

Comment: The integral is with respect to x and the limit is in terms of n so moving the limit doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @karthikeyakurella, Not in the case of this integral, but there are situations when it is not always allowed. You should read about Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem and Monotone convergence theorem.